# Gestures not working for UIPageViewController that contains UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement something like the notification center for my app:

There is a `UIPageViewController` since I want the swipe left/right gestures to work and inside I need to display 4 `UITableViewControllers`. On top there is a `UISegmentedCotrol` to show "which tab is selected"

Everything works, except the swipe gestures for changing the pages, as if the TableView is capturing the gestures and not letting the PageView do its job.

I do not need my TableViews to be editable, since they are just articles from a website. Only the `didSelectRowAt(indexPath)` is enough to do whatever I need to (segue to an "articleViewController).

If anyone has an idea how to keep `UIPageViewController`'s gestures working with a `TableViewController` inside let me know. Thank you

Comment: Ended up using a library for this purpose, [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) I recommend it to anyone having a similar situation as it takes care of all the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

var pageviewController = UIPageViewController()

```
pageviewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)

    pageviewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320 , height: 568)

    pageviewController.setViewControllers([arrayControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    addChildViewController(pageviewController)
    viewToAdd.addSubview(pageviewController.view)
    pageviewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            //right view controller

            print("Swipe Right")

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            //left view controller

            print("Swipe left")

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working in my case... I am instantiating the PageViewController from Storyboard and each TableViewController in code. I want to keep the default behaviour (of being able to slide between the "pages" visually), which works If I don't use a TableViewController (or even when swiping from a normal UIViewController to a UITableViewController) but not the opposite way